# How to join call using "Skype for Business Web App" on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, ms-office, skype

Using my Mac I'm trying to join a conference call hosted using [Skype for Business Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/skype-for-business-server-2019). But every time I try, it seems to send me in loops with the same prompts to install the plugin again and again. Here's a screenshot of the screen I start with.

[image: Prompt to join meeting using Skype for Business Web App]

---

*1. Join with Web App*

If I enter my name and click "Join the meeting" my browser downloads `SkypeForBusinessPlugin.pkg` (md5sum = a4958d5aa5c7dbe17774bcd6e4492106). I can run this and choose to "Install for me only". After installation I see a new plug-in in `~/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins` called `SkypeForBusinessPlugin-15.8.bundle`, so the installation is apparently successful. The bundle ID is `com.microsoft.skypeforbusiness.plugin`. I don't know which browser this is for, but I assume it should work in Safari. When I go back to the same page after installing the plugin, I am either prompted to install the plugin again, or I get this error message:

> Plug-in installation is taking longer than usual. We recommend you join the meeting now.

If I try to join at this point I end up in a "Virtual Lobby" but I'm never able to advance from that point, presumably because the plugin is not working. Could the plugin be incompatible with 64-bit macOS Catalina?

---

*Join using Lync for Mac*

I tried the second option of using Lync for Mac, but when I try to run Lync I get this error:

> “Microsoft Lync” needs to be updated.
>   The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of macOS. Contact the developer for more information.
>   https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208436

So I guess I can't use Lync for Mac on macOS Catalina.

#### Known workarounds

I installed Skype for Business on my iPad and had no trouble connecting to the call that way. But I want to use my Mac for this.

#### Additional details

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76). My normal browser is Firefox 74 (64-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Skype for Business on Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54108) from Microsoft and install it. Once installed, links to join a meeting will open in the native application without needing to install any web plug-ins.

The Skype for Business Web App doesn't seem to work on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the above answer, but on Catalina, I can't join from the regular link, I had to change to launch the app separately, join as guest, then punch in the meeting url and my name to join the meeting.